# Unable to initialize UNIXServer with vagrant

Tags: ruby, sockets, vagrant

It looks like some permissions issues:

```
$ irb
require 'socket'; UNIXServer.new('/vagrant/tmp/sock')
=> Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - "/vagrant/tmp/sock"
```

But user `vagrant` has permissions to write in `/vagrant/tmp`

```
$ whoami
vagrant

$ ls -la /vagrant/tmp
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  68 Feb 22 23:18 .
```

So it's not obvious for me what's going wrong. I use latest ruby

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-linux]
```

And ubuntu 14.04:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
end
```

Answer (score 0):

see [Unicorn fails to start on Vagrant box due to Errno::EPERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388342/unicorn-fails-to-start-on-vagrant-box-due-to-errnoeperm) for a solution (use a file outside of the Vagrant virtual shared folder for the socket)

Comment: Could you also outline the solution in your answer here? Websites have the habit of disappearing.